# How to get CSRF token Value at javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, csrf, wavemaker

I have requirement like that, when I send request, `CSRF-token` should be send with it. I Explore some SO questions, But I can't find Solution.

I have written Code like bellow to add token when request being sent,

```
 var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
        token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
        this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', "xyz12345");
        //this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',getCSRFTokenValue());
        return send.apply(this, arguments);
    }
```

This is Working Fine, But now i need to add CSRF-Token in function in place of `xyz12345`.

I have tried ajax function as below . 
`

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/test/"
            //data: { CSRF: getCSRFTokenValue()}
        }).done(function (data) {
        var csrfToken = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
        if (csrfToken) {
            var cookie = JSON.parse($.cookie('helloween'));
            cookie.csrf = csrfToken;
            $.cookie('helloween', JSON.stringify(cookie));
        }

        $('#helloweenMessage').html(data.message);

    });
```

But it is not Yet Worked.
So my question is:
 *How to get js side  CSRF-Token Value?*

Comment: What is the question? Is the question how you get the CSRF header or a value into a cookie?

Comment: @limelights, I have CSRF-token in responce now, same token I want to pass in request also, So, just wanted to get Value of `CSEF-Token` .Here ajax function is not by me. it's taken.

Comment: By adding this:  `token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');`  I'm getting `token` as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get my CSRF Token by this way, 
By adding function :

```
$.get('CSRFTokenManager.do', function(data) {
   var send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send,
   token =data;
   document.cookie='X-CSRF-Token='+token;
   XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data) {
       this.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token',token);
       //dojo.cookie("X-CSRF-Token", "");

       return send.apply(this, arguments);
   };
});
```

Where `CSRFTokenManager.do` will be called from `CSRFTokenManager` Class.
Now It is adding token in header and cookie in every request.

Answer (score 3):

you need to do this in new Laravel

```
var csrf = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'value': value, '_token': csrf },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('value set');
        }
    });
```